Locating the full path of a tool to run using ProcessStartInfo in C#
I'm developing a small CLI that calls the dotnet.exe application with code similar to this:
var dotnet = new ProcessStartInfo("dotnet", ...)
{
    // ...
};
var process = Process.Start(dotnet);

(the parameters and settings are not relevant for the question why I have removed them)
The code is running fine. But I'm getting a warning from SonarCloud that I should specify the full path for dotnet.exe. I can see the point, since someone would be able to inject a malicious version of that tool in the PATH and my tool would run that.
My question is. How would I locate the path of dotnet.exe? ChatGPT suggested me to fetch the location from DOTNET_ROOT but that is not something I have on my machine so I doubt my users will have that either. Another suggestion is to run where or which, but then I will probably get a similar warning to specify the full path for those tools.
I know that I don't HAVE to implement everything that static code analyzers tell me. But in this case I think it's a valid suggestion. I also know that if someone would be successful in injecting a new dotnet.exe, the same problem would exist when the users run dotnet build etc.

ChatGPT suggested random text generators know nothing about programming and even computers. The only reason dotnet runs is because the executable is in the path. Why is the application calling dotnet though? Why does a .NET application have to call the dotnet tool instead of loading a library?

not relevant for the question they are. There may be multiple runtimes installed on a machine. On Windows the dotnet tool itself is located in %ProgramFiles%\dotnet, eg C:\Program Files\dotnet and C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet on most machines.

"I can see the point" No you didn't, if this is the point, do all the dotnet tutorials, examples, and the C# dev kits ignore this threat? After all, they are all running dotnet xxx directly, rather than specifying the full path.

@PanagiotisKanavos I never said that ChatGPT know anything about programming. The only reason I mentioned it is that every time I ask a question after ChatGPT was introduced, people either paste a reply from ChatGPT as the answer or say "You should ask ChatGPT about this". The arguments for dotnet are not relevant, no. Thank you for your input.

@shingo You are right that this is a general problem and not specific to my tool. I'm not sure if you can decide if I see the point or not, though ;) Thank you for your input.

Using the full path won't help if the malicious software overwrote the original dotnet.exe - which I assume is possible (I'm not a hacker). Is there a possibility to suppress warnings of sonarcloud in source code?

@001 That's true and a good point. I was only wondering if there's a good way to do this. Thank you for the link, BTW. I've already added multiple Sonar ignores. Some suggestions are really great while others aren't :)

@ThomasArdal you have to explain what you want. There are ways to find any binary's location in any shell, but that won't solve the problem pointed by SonarCloud. The best option would be to avoid having to use dotnet. After that, you could look for the location of whatever runs your own program (assuming it isn't self-contained). Not sure if that's possible though

@ThomasArdal as for a hacker overwriting the installed dotnet.exe, you've already lost the game because your own application is using that runtime. For that to happen, someone would have to run code with elevated privileges though, because Program Files is read-only.

All of your comments are good and speak against trying to handle this "problem". Thanks y'all.

It's probably better to retrieve the full path of the executable from configuration instead of depending on the PATH. If the user somehow installed dotnet.exe or a global tool in a custom location, they can change that location. You can load OS-specific configuration files, use environment variables or Docker/Kubernetes settings to control the location of the executable

dotnet.exe is dotnet cli or your custom dotnet cli app? @ThomasArdal

It's the dotnet CLI. My tool is updating NuGet packages using dotnet.exe.

injecting a new dotnet.exe -> highly possible

maybe you can release your CLI app with dotnet binaries embedded
and then simply you can get path to the dotnet.exe using:
string dotnetPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+"\\binary\\dotnet.exe"

I. Get the dotnet binaries of your favourite version

II. Create a folder named "binary" in the project
III. Set the build action to "Content"
IV. Set "Copy to output directory" to "Copy if newer"

someone can inject their own code in your own CLI app, signing CLI is another thing out of context of this question

I don't think embedding dotnet is a good option for my application. It is simply a wrapper of what the user currently has installed and I want them to pick exactly the dotnet version they prefer. My question didn't provide these details, though. So, thank you for the suggestion still.

This answer doesn't show any kind of embedding. You can't just download the runtime or SDK installer and call the dotnet.exe file inside it

it can be done, embed the actual exe as I said or create your app as self-contained dotnet. OP agrees the solution but looking for another option. picking another dotnet version can be another question. the dotnet binaries highlighted above is not installer, its offline file.
